# How to extract data from an .APK file?

Tags: applications, settings, apk

I want to extract or copy every detail that .apk contain, like for example extracting data from `whatsapp.apk` or `linked-in.apk` or `twitter.apk`.

Please note that I dont want to extract my personal data from any installed app on my phone instead I want extract the **data and images** which the app developer had added while making the app.

Answer (score 5):

An APK is the same as a JAR file which is the same as a ZIP file.

Rename the .APK to a .ZIP and then extract the .ZIP

Answer (score 2):

As suggested earlier, Apktool is a good option,

**Requirements:**

- [Java Runtime Environment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html)
- [Windows wrapper script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/master/scripts/windows/apktool.bat) (Right click, Save Link As apktool.bat)
- [Apktool.jar](https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads/)

(For Linux and Mac OS the files and installation instructions are also available:  [Installation for Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/))

**Usage**

Copy the apktool.bat and apktool.jar files to a folder preferably with no spaces eg inside the  `C:\ directory`. (e.g C:\Apktool)

1. Open command prompt by pressing shift and right click simultaneously.
2. In the command prompt type `apktool d [apkname.apk]` (e.g `apktool d WhatsApp`)
3. Find the extracted apk in the folder with the apk name (in this case (`C:\Apktool\WhatsApp`)
4. You can now browse through the folder to find all resources of the app e.g `manifest.xml` and PNG images in `res` folder or doing a search.

Acknowledgements:

[Apktool a tool for reverse engineering](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)